# OpenGL: Count Number of Triangles / Objects drawn

Tags: opengl

For an Visual Studio developed OpenGL Game, is there any possibility to count the Triangles or Objects (meshes without connection to each other) that are drawn with the help of the API? I did not find any information on that. Counting them manually seems artificially painful.

Comment: What do you mean by "drawn"?  Triangles passed into a `glDraw*()` call?  Or triangles that survived the transform and clipping pipeline to actually have at least one fragment end up in the color buffer?  What's an "object"?

Comment: Why would it be "artificially painful"? You *tell* the API how much stuff to draw. That means that you *know* how much stuff gets drawn because you told the system to draw it. The only places where it might get painful are if you're using primitive restart (which complicates the conversion from vertex count to primitive count) or if you're using tessellation/geometry shaders to amplify geometry. Or are you talking about how many polygons are *visible*?

Comment: @genpfault: yes, i was unclear. I mean with the clipping. I am supposed to implement a feature, so only the visible camera view is drawn, and not the unseen surrounding. Even though, this feature shall be able to be turned on and off fluently, and leet into a decrease/increase of the number of Triangles drawn.

Objects, well the gameobjects that are consistingof one mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, and the result is exactly the same as in blender.

The drawn objects have of course a lot of meshes. The drawn mesh vertex count stored in a simple variable which set to zero and afterwards summed up and divided by three on each render loop iteration.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is the simple variable? An example could be great.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't really a hassle to do it "yourself", you could override/redirect all `glDraw*()` calls.

I did something similar a few years ago, where I wanted to count the amount of draw calls any given frame made (for debug builds). I implemented it by having a macro for each `glDraw*()`. Which looked like:

```
int drawCallCount = 0;

#define glDrawArrays(...) \
    do { glad_glDrawArrays(__VA_ARGS__); ++drawCallCount; } while (0)

// etc glDraw*()
```

Then at the end of each frame I would read `drawCallCount` and reset it back to `0`.

*Note that I was/am using [GLAD](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad).*

Considering `glDrawArrays(GLenum mode, GLint first, GLsizei count)`. Then you would check if `mode` is `GL_TRIANGLES` then `(count - first) / 3` would be the amount of triangles that draw call made.

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Mode              | Triangles           |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| GL_TRIANGLES      | (count - first) / 3 |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP | (count - 2 - first) |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| GL_TRIANGLE_FAN   | (count - 2 - first) |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: The idea looks promising. Even though, i am not sure if i could use that library, since i cannot take any library that does OpenGL calls (university course restriction).

Comment: @Andrea GLAD is simply and OpenGL loader. Thus simply change `glad_glDrawArrays` to whatever you have at hand.